# Make archived documents available for links

Tags: email, archive, lotus-notes

What happens: users mailbox is archived locally for reduce mail box size. Other db's contains links to e-mail messages and are not longer available, because the message is gone from the mailbox to the archive.

Is there any way to indicate a fail-over when the message isn't found in the mailbox (at least for the local user) ?

Answer (score 1):

No , I think there is not any way to indicate a fail-over when the message isn't found in the mailbox. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Assuming this question is referring to the built-in archiving in Notes, you're not wrong. The doclink is basically a reference to the ReplicaID of the database plus the UNID of the document. When the document is removed from the mail database, there's no way for the doclink to know.  But with some third-party archiving systems, there might be a "stub" that is left behind in the mail database, with software that can be installed so that when the doclink finds the stub it would automatically locate the archived document. Since the question refers to local archiving, I doubt that is the case here